# Not able to unmount a Nas folder, target busy

Tags: ubuntu, samba, shared-directory, unmount, umount

I have some issues to unmount my Nas folder. When I try to unmount it with `sudo umount /media/Nas6To` i get a message telling me that the device is busy, and I cannot unmount it:

```
thomas@NZXT:~$ sudo umount /media/Nas6To 
umount: /media/Nas6To: the target is active.
```

I have found on different post using `fuser` and `lsof` to identify the process keeping it busy. Unfortunately those commands returns nothing.

```
thomas@NZXT:~$ fuser -m /media/Nas6To
thomas@NZXT:~$

thomas@NZXT:~$ lsof | grep Nas6To
thomas@NZXT:~$
```

I would like to undestand what is keeping it busy. And what I could do be able to unmount it with `sudo umount /media/Nas6To`

**My configuration:**

Fstab configuration:

```
//10.0.0.110/6To     /media/Nas6To cifs username=xxxx,password=xxxx,uid=1000,vers=2.0,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0770,noauto 0 0
```

Directory permissions (when mounted):

```
thomas@NZXT:~$ ls -la /media
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   8 root    root 4096 feb.  28 14:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 root    root 4096 jan.  30 15:25 ..
drwxrwx---   2 thomas  root    0 mars  13 13:59 Nas6To
```

OS (Xubuntu):

```
thomas@NZXT:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi after some time I found the fix using wireshark.

I was not able to unmount because my computer was sending lot of SMB packet related to the trash on background.

**Note:** The following commands will empty your Trash. Before continuing, check that it doesn't contains any thing that you want to keep.

**To fix it:**

- Delete your Nas Trash with `rm -r /PathToYourNAS/.Trash-1000/`
- Flush your computers Trash with `rm -r ~/.local/share/Trash/*`